# Parametric representation of this equation: $3x+5y+2z=20$

Tags: systems-of-equations, parametric

I have this equation:

$3x+5y+2z=20$

Of the plane $3x+5y+2z=20$ give two direction vectors that are perpendicular to each other.

I have used linear algebra and came up with the following parametric equation: $\left( 20/3,0,0\right)+t\left(-\dfrac 53,1,0\right)+u\left(-\dfrac 23,0,1\right)$

Is this a correct representation? I am not so sure.

so i have the two vectors $<-5/3,1,0>$ and $<-2/3,0,1>$ which if i take the dot product of with the normal vector $(3,5,2)$i will get zero thus the two vectors are perpendicular to the normal vector.

Comment: one such vector is given by $$\vec{n}=[3;5;2]$$

Comment: Does it work when $t=u=0?$

Comment: @saulspatz What do you mean? Does it work?

Comment: I mean if you substitute $u=0, t=0$ into your formula, do you get a vector perpendicular to the plane?  Whenever you get an answer, you should try to check that it's correct.

Comment: @saulspatz why should i make those two equal two zero?

Comment: When you say this is a parametric solution, it means that for every value of the parameters, you get a solution.  I just picked $t=u=0$ as the easiest example to compute.  It might just have well asked if it works for $t=1,u=2.$

Comment: I i pick zero i see i am left with a vector that is on the plane

Comment: Shouldn’t you be trying to find a pair of linearly independent vectors that are *parallel* to the plane?

Comment: I want to give of the plane two direction vectors that are perpendicular to each other

Comment: I have changed the question did you see it??? That was what i wanted to answer

Comment: The question still asks for two vectors perpendicular to each other, but your two are not.

Comment: @coffeemath yes i see . Now when i finally understand this question properly. I will have to find a vector to 3x+5y+2z=0 now for this we can use the vector (1,-1,1) now we wanna find a vector which is perpendicular to that vector and to the 3x+5y+2z=0 now of i solve those two equations i get the vector (-7,1,8) which is perpendicular to the normal and to the vector (1,-1,1) so we are done.

Comment: Mark-- Yes, the new two vectors are normal to each other and also to (3,5,2). Suggest you put this up as an answer; it's considered OK here to answer your own question.

Comment: @coffeemath ok thank you as a side note if you look at my parametric equation in my question it is a correct way of describing the plane right ?

Comment: It's correct. Only need to check that (20/3,0,0) is on the plane, and that the two vectors after t,u are normal to (3,5,2) and neither is a multiple of the other for that.

Comment: @coffeemath ok thank you so much!!!